# React-Native TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.screenProps.cities.map')

Tags: react-native, undefined, typeerror

Getting error above when in file cities.js when trying to run program. The cities.js screen should display all cities that have been added from the addCity.js screen.

Im new to react-native and not sure how to use props and referencing properly. any help with this would be very appreciated. Thank you

cities.js :

```
import React from 'react';
import {
    View,
    Text,
    StyleSheet,
    ScrollView,
    TouchableWithoutFeedback
} from 'react-native';

import { colors } from '../theme'

export default class Cities extends React.Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        title: 'Cities',
        headerTitleStyle: {
            color: 'white',
            fontSize: 20,
            fontWeight: '400'
        }
    }
    viewCity = () =>{

    }

    render(){

        return (

            <ScrollView>
                        <View>
                        {

                            this.props.screenProps.cities.map((city, index) => (
                                <View>
                                    <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() =>this.viewCity(city)}>
                                        <View style={styles.cityContainer}>
                                        <Text style={styles.city}>{city.city}</Text>
                                        <Text style={style.country}>{city.country}</Text>

                                        </View>

                                    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>

                                </View>
                                ))
                        }
                        </View>
            </ScrollView>

        )
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    cityContainer: {
        padding: 10,
        borderBottomWidth: 2,
        borderBottomColor: colors.primary
    }
})
```

Comment: first check this.props.screenProps.cities is not equal to null

Comment: the array was null. I used this if statement `if(this.props.screenProps.cities && this.props.screenProps.cities.length)` to check before now

Answer (score 0):

You should use [loadsh](https://lodash.com/) because it will take care of null or undefined objects or arrays like this

first install lodash

```
npm i lodash
```

then use it like this

```
import _ from 'lodash'

const cities = _.get(this.props.screenProps, 'cities.map', [])

if(_.size(cities) > 0){
// do something
}
```

Lodash is a well recommended utility library for JavaScript.